# PyQt5 && QML exporting enum

Tags: python, qt, enums, pyqt, qml

Is it possible to export `enum` from `Python` to `QML` instance?

```
class UpdateState():
    Nothing = 0
    CheckingUpdate = 1
    NoGameFound = 2
    Updating = 3
```

How I want to use it in `qml`:

```
import PythonController 1.0

PythonController {
    id: controller
}

Item {
    visible: controller.UpdateState.Nothing ? true : false
}
```

Comment: I don't know how `Python` works with `Qt` but in `C++` I can export enums with `Q_ENUMS`. May be Python-QML has some similar ability to export enums to the meta-object system?

Comment: In PyQt5, there's [QtCore.Q_ENUMS](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/metaobjects.html). PyQt4 also has it, but it doesn't seem to work in the same way, and AFAICS it isn't documented.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine, as long as the enum is registered with `Q_ENUMS` and defined inside a class registered with the QML engine. Here's a small example:

**example.py**

```
from sys import exit, argv

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtProperty, Q_ENUMS, QObject
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, qmlRegisterType
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication


class Switch(QObject):

    class State:
        On = 0
        Off = 1

    Q_ENUMS(State)

    stateChanged = pyqtSignal(State, arguments=['state'])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._state = Switch.State.Off

    @pyqtProperty(State, notify=stateChanged)
    def state(self):
        return self._state

    @state.setter
    def state(self, state):
        if state != self._state:
            self._state = state
            self.stateChanged.emit(self._state)


app = None


def main():
    global app

    app = QGuiApplication(argv)

    qmlRegisterType(Switch, 'Switch', 1, 0, 'Switch')

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load('example.qml')

    exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**example.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

import Switch 1.0

Window {
    title: 'QML Enum Example'
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    color: colorSwitch.state === Switch.On ? "green" : "red"

    Switch {
        id: colorSwitch
        state: Switch.Off
    }

    Text {
        text: "Press window to switch state"
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked: {
            if (colorSwitch.state === Switch.Off)
                colorSwitch.state = Switch.On
            else
                colorSwitch.state = Switch.Off
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.