# Register Enums for QML in PySide2

Tags: python, enums, qml, qt5, pyside2

I'd like to export enums from Python to QML using PySide2.
It is possible using PyQt5 see [PyQt5 && QML exporting enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004250/pyqt5-qml-exporting-enum)

However the required Q_ENUMS does not exist in PySide2.
Is there another way in PySide2?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but with newer versions of PySide2 you can now use the @QEnum decorator.
It requires you to use a QObject as a wrapper (similar to the C++ namespace you'd put around your enum).

Here is an example of what it could look like:

```
class UserState(QObject):
    @QEnum
    class Options(Enum):
        ONLINE = 0
        OFFLINE = 1
        BUSY = 2
```

In order to access this enum in QML, you need to [register](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType) it first:

```
qmlRegisterType(UserState, "yourlibname", 1, 0, "UserState")
```

And then import it in your QML:

```
import yourlibname 1.0
```

Comment: Could you please add a usage example inside QML? How do you access the `Options` enum? And can you use it as an argument passed to a Python Slot expecting an 'Options' enum or is it only usable in QML?

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 The actual enum for QML is `UserState` so you can just access it using `UserState.ONLINE` for example. If you want to be able to use the enum the same way in QML as in Python, you can look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057987/use-qenum-like-a-python-enum this implementation makes it more clear that the enum is `UserState` and not `Options`.