# Use QEnum like a Python Enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qml, pyside2

Let's say I have a python enum:

```
class UserState(Enum):
    OFFLINE = auto()
    ONLINE = auto()
    BUSY = auto()
```

I can access the different options with `UserState.ONLINE`, `UserState.OFFLINE` or `UserState.BUSY`.
If I wanted to make this a QEnum so I can use it in QML, I'd need to wrap it inside a `QObject` like this:

```
class UserState(QObject):
    @QEnum
    class Options(Enum):
        OFFLINE = auto()
        ONLINE = auto()
        BUSY = auto()
```

In QML I can access this enum now the same way I'd access a normal python enum in python. However if I wanted to access this enum from python, I'd have to write `UserState.Options.ONLINE`.

How can I create an enum that will work in python as well as QML using the same syntax?

*I have found a solution for this which I will post in the answers section. However it involves nested metaclasses which just doesn't look right. I think the optimal solution would be a class that derives from QObject as well as Enum to have all the functionality for every context.*

*If anyone can provide a version which works like that, I will make that the accepted answer.
Otherwise you can tell me, why my solution actually is a good one.*

Comment: Have you tried creating an issue over at the [Qt bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa)? They may be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a class I have written which adds the support I'm asking for in the question:

```
class CustomEnumMeta(type(Enum)):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        # don't change type of base class
        if name == "CustomEnum":
            return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        original_attrs = attrs.copy()
        enum = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        class WrapperMeta(type(QObject)):
            def __new__(cls, wrapper_name, wrapper_bases, wrapper_attrs):
                return super().__new__(cls, wrapper_name, wrapper_bases, {**original_attrs, **wrapper_attrs})

        class Wrapper(QObject, metaclass=WrapperMeta):
            QEnum(enum)

        Wrapper.__name__ = name

        return Wrapper


class CustomEnum(Enum, metaclass=CustomEnumMeta):
    pass
```

The CustomEnum class can be inherited just like a normal python enum:

```
class UserState(CustomEnum):
    OFFLINE = auto()
    ONLINE = auto()
    BUSY = auto()
```

Now you can use `UserState` the same way in python as in QML. This is a valid statement for both python and QML: `UserState.ONLINE`

My implementation works by replacing the original class with a QObject, nesting the original class. And then copying all the attributes of the nested class to the outer class to make them accessible from python.

Comment: I suppose it should be `metaclass=CustomEnumMeta`

Comment: @musicamante oh yeah sorry, I had it under a different name in my project. I edited the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Why would you create `WrapperMeta` on every  `__new__` call?

Comment: @ניר because `original_attrs` can be different on every call.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call QEnum inside the class and define the enum outside.

Example (PySide6):

**file**: main.py

```py
import sys
from enum import Enum
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtCore import Property, QEnum, QObject
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import (
    QmlElement,
    QQmlApplicationEngine,
    qmlRegisterSingletonInstance,
)

QML_IMPORT_NAME = "com.example.app"
QML_IMPORT_MAJOR_VERSION = 1


class Status(Enum):
    Connected, Disconnected, Stale = range(3)


@QmlElement
class Enums(QObject):
    QEnum(Status)


class App(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None)

    @Property(int, constant=True)
    def enumValue(self):
        return Status.Connected.value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    app = App()
    qmlRegisterSingletonInstance(QObject, "com.example.app", 1, 0, "App", app)
    qml_file = Path(__file__).parent / "main.qml"
    engine.load(str(qml_file))

    sys.exit(loop.exec())
```

**file**: main.qml

```js
import QtQuick
import com.example.app 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 700
    title: "POC"

    Rectangle {
        color: App.enumValue == Enums.Status.Connected ? "green" : "red"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Full code [here](https://github.com/nrbnlulu/Qt-answers/tree/master/QtQuick/67057987-QEnum)